# "dich" in "Ich glaube (an) dich" — accusative or dative?

Tags: dative, accusative

Is the "dir" in "Ich glaube an dich." in accusative case while "dich" in "Ich glaube dich." in dative case, not the other way?

I encounter this in Duolingo and it seems very quirky and counter-intuitive.

Comment: "Ich glaube an dir." is simlpy wrong. Correct is "Ich glaube an dich."

Comment: @IQV Sorry. I have corrected it back.

Comment: Sorry, but now "Ich glaube dich." is wrong. Here "Ich glaube dir." was correct!

Comment: What????!!!!! frustrating!

Comment: Maybe. It's german. ;-)

Comment: You can get some hints from dictionaries. E.g. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glauben): to believe (to think someone/something exists = an + acc.; to think something someone says is correct = dat.) — The German version is even more clear: »jemandem glauben« (Dativ),  »an jemanden (/etwas) glauben« (Akkusativ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Glauben" can take both a dative and an accusative object. The person you believe must be in the dative, and what you believe in the accusative. Example:

> Ich glaube dir deine Erklärung.

The accusative object is often a subordinary clause (Objektsatz). Example:

> Ich glaube dir, dass das keine Absicht war.

With the preposition "an" things are different. In that case, you must use the accusative after "an".

Answer (score 3):

In German language, you should not only learn the verb but also its details like whether it is seperable or not, takes dative or accusative, accepts a preposition or not, must take an object or not necessarily and so on.

In your question, *glauben* takes dative and because of this reason, it should be;

> Ich glaube dir

or if you want to emphasize "believing with taste of the trust", the verb *glauben* takes preposition **an** and in such a case, you can also say;

> ich glaube an dich

And you can also ask why did preposition **an** take an accusative instead of dative. It would require a huge explanation but briefly, I can say some prepositions take accusative, some prepositions take dative and some prepositions are two-way prepositions, meaning they can take either accusative or dative based on the situation. The preposition *an*, which *glauben* takes, is also one of the two-way prepositions and in case of *glauben*, it takes accusative instead of dative, resulting ich glaube an dich instead of ich glaube an dir.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's *dich*, it can only be in the accusative case. And *dir* can only be in the dative case. These are *fixed* pronominal forms.